# Why use left join at all

Tags: sql, left-join

I am looking at the following link [Left Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

If left join uses all elements from table 1 and doesn't care about table 2, why not just write:

```
SELECT table1.column_name(s)
FROM table1
```

instead of writing

```
SELECT table1.column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Comment: "and doesn't care about table 2" -- It doesn't say that. It doesn't even say anything that I can understand misinterpreting as saying that. And it contains an example that retrieves data from two tables.

Comment: Sometimes `LEFT JOIN` can be used to find the disjoint between two tables, i.e. records which are exclusively present/absent in one table but not the other.

Comment: What's the motivation for this question? Have you just totally misunderstood what left joins even are?

Comment: That particular example from the link confused me but your example below shows me a case where left join might be relevant.

Comment: You may want to take some time and grok this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't that one cares about the values in `TABLE1` and, as you write, doesn't care about `TABLE2`.  It is that one cares about the values in `TABLE1` and also about the values in `TABLE2` *if they exist*.

Suppose you want a report of employees and their managers.  You wouldn't want to exclude the president of your company simply because he doesn't have a manager.  So, you would write it as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT e.employee_name, m.employee_name manager_name
FROM   employees e 
LEFT JOIN employees m ON m.employee_id = e.manager_id
```

That way, you will get a row with your president's name and a `NULL` manager name for the president.  If you had written it as an INNER join, you wouldn't have gotten a row for the president at all.

Answer (score 3):

A LEFT JOIN on another table without a WHERE clause is indeed quite unnessairy, when only columns from the first table are needed.

In fact, it could return more rows than expected.

For example:

First some sample data:

Table1:

```
Id  Text1    SomeKey
1   Tralala  10
2   Joehoe   20
3   Trololo  30
```

Table2:

```
Id  SomeKey Text2 
1   10      Blah
2   20      Bleh
3   20      Blergh
```

A query only on Table1 would return 3 rows.

But a query with a left join on SomeKey would return 4 rows:

```
select t1.Text1
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on (t1.SomeKey = t2.SomeKey)
```

returns:

```
Text1
-------
Tralala
Joehoe
Joehoe
Trololo
```

A common reason why one would do such a left join, without selecting fields from the joined table, is to find records in Table1 that don't have a match in Table2. Or use criteria based on Table2 fields.

```
select t1.Text1, t1.SomeKey 
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on (t1.SomeKey = t2.SomeKey)
where t2.Id is null;
```

returns:

```
Text1    SomeKey
-------- -------
Trololo  30
```

Comment: That is not the reason why LEFT join exists and it is only one of the ways (and an inefficient way) to find records only in table1.

Answer (score 2):

"If left join uses all elements from table 1 and doesn't care about table 2"

This statement is wrong and also the sample SQLs are not even similar.

LEFT JOIN means:
All the rows from "LEFT" table, regardless there is a match on "RIGHT" or not AND all the rows from "RIGHT" where there is a match. For example think of Customers and their Orders. You might have 100 Customers and not all of them yet have Orders.

```
select *
from Customers c 
LEFT JOIN Orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID;
```

would retrieve all those 100 Customer rows, where those that do not have an Order have NULL for Orders' columns and if one has N Orders, its Customer row is repeated for each of those Orders. ie:

Customers: (CustomerId, CustomerName)

```
1, Customer1
2, Customer2
3, Customer3
```

Orders:(OrderId,CustomerId,OrderDate,...)

```
1, 1, 2000/1/1 10:00:00, ...
2, 1, 2000/1/5 11:00:00, ...
3, 2, 2000/1/6 18:00:00, ...
```

Result would be:

```
1, Customer1, 1, 1, 2000/1/1 10:00:00, ...
1, Customer1, 2, 1, 2000/1/5 11:00:00, ...
2, Customer2, 3, 2, 2000/1/6 18:00:00, ...
3, Customer3, NULL, NULL, NULL, ...
```

As you can see, it doesn't select "elements" only from LEFT table, it does from both. You can specify individual or all columns from either table:

```
select c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, o.OrderDate, o.OrderID
from Customers c 
LEFT JOIN Orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID;

select c.*
from Customers c 
LEFT JOIN Orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID;

select c.*, o.OrderId, o.OrderDate
from Customers c 
LEFT JOIN Orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID;
```

etc.