# SQL - Identify a record's status based on dates from another table (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table called `worker_log`:

| log_date | total_workers | store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2 | Ralphs |
| 2021-02-01 | 0 | Ralphs |
| 2021-03-01 | 3 | Ralphs |
| 2021-01-01 | 3 | Benny's |
| 2021-02-01 | 0 | Benny's |
| 2021-03-01 | 1 | Benny's |

For Ralphs, from 1/1/21 to 1/31/21, there were 2 total workers. From 2/1 to 2/28/21, there were 0 total workers. So on 2/1/21, the number of workers changed from 2 to 0. From 3/1/21 to the present, there were 3 total workers.  So on 3/1/21, the number of workers changed from 0 to 3.

I have the following TEMPORARY table called `request_log`:

| ticket_no | request_date | store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 2021-01-03 | Ralphs |
| 10001 | 2021-01-08 | Ralphs |
| 10002 | 2021-02-05 | Ralphs |
| 10003 | 2021-04-03 | Ralphs |
| 10004 | 2021-01-21 | Benny's |
| 10005 | 2021-02-23 | Benny's |
| 10006 | 2021-04-03 | Benny's |

I need to create another table, called `requests` that shows if a request ticket was requested on a certain date, if there were workers available based on the `log_date` column `worker_log` table. The end result of the `requests` table should look like this:

| ticket_no | request_date | store | workers_available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 2021-01-03 | Ralphs | true |
| 10001 | 2021-01-08 | Ralphs | true |
| 10002 | 2021-02-05 | Ralphs | false |
| 10003 | 2021-04-03 | Ralphs | true |
| 10004 | 2021-01-21 | Benny's | true |
| 10005 | 2021-02-23 | Benny's | false |
| 10006 | 2021-04-03 | Benny's | true |

How would I go about this with a SQL script?

I don't know how to implement it with LATERAL joins.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, it is necessary to:

1. use an INNER JOIN to compare the common identifier between the two tables, in this case request_date and log_date
2. use a CASE expression to create a new `workers_available` column which sets to True if the total_workers variable is greater than 0, and false if otherwise.

As such, this can be accomplished as follows:

```
select t1.ticket_no, t1.request_date, t1.store, case when t2.total_workers>0 then 'true' else 'false' end as workers_available from request_log as t1 inner join worker_log as t2 on t1.request_date=t2.log_date;
```

To test this query, I created two rows of hypothetical data from the above tables - one where the total_workers was greater than 0 and one where it was not.

```
select * from request_log;
 ticket_no |    request_date     | store  
-----------+---------------------+--------
     10000 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | Ralphs
     10001 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | Ralphs
(2 rows)

select * from worker_log;
      log_date       | total_workers | store  
---------------------+---------------+--------
 2021-01-03 00:00:00 |             2 | Ralphs
 2021-01-08 00:00:00 |             0 | Ralphs
(2 rows)
```

Upon running the above query, we can see that the entry where total_workers=2 has an entry of True, while the entry where total_workers=0 has an entry of False.

```
select t1.ticket_no, t1.request_date, t1.store, case when t2.total_workers>0 then 'true' else 'false' end as workers_available from request_log as t1 inner join worker_log as t2 on t1.request_date=t2.log_date;
 ticket_no |    request_date     | store  | workers_available 
-----------+---------------------+--------+-------------------
     10000 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | Ralphs | true
     10001 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | Ralphs | false
(2 rows)
```

Please note that you may also find this tutorial on [case expressions](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! So I'm not sure about this part of the JOIN: `t1.request_date=t2.log_date`. This is because the request_date value and log_date values are not always going to be the same. For example, in the `worker_log` table, from 1/1/21 to 1/31/21, there were 2 total workers. From 2/1 to 2/28/21, there were 0 total workers. From 3/1/21 to the present, there were 3 total workers.

Comment: In that case, what ID are you using to join the two tables? When I look at the two tables above, worker_log does not have a ticket_no variable.

Comment: Joining by store (in the actual data there is a store_id that can be used to join)

Comment: Then this is the id that must be used to join the two tables - that wasn't clear from the original question.

Comment: @user1893649 Debug questions require a [mre]. Otherwise they merit closure--having answers blocked. Posts that merit closure should be closed, not answered. Please clarify posts via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. [ask] [answer] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

Using a `left join lateral(...) on true` you can run a "correlated subquery" that locates the most recent worker_log entry at or prior to the request. From that you get the number of workers available at that time and you can use the case expression as requested (other columns for reference only):

```
select
      r.ticket_no   
    , r.request_date    
    , r.store   
    , case when w.total_workers > 0 then 'true' else 'false' end as workers_available
    , w.total_workers
    , w.log_date
from request_log as r
left join lateral (
  select total_workers, log_date
  from worker_log as wl
  where r.store = wl.store
  and r.request_date >= wl.log_date 
  order by 
       wl.log_date DESC
  limit 1
  ) as w on true
;
```

**Result**

```
ticket_no   request_date    store   workers_available   total_workers   log_date
10000       2021-01-03      Ralphs  true                2               2021-01-01
10001       2021-01-08      Ralphs  true                2               2021-01-01
10002       2021-02-05      Ralphs  false               0               2021-02-01
10003       2021-04-03      Ralphs  true                3               2021-03-01
10004       2021-01-21      Benny's true                3               2021-01-01
10005       2021-02-23      Benny's false               0               2021-02-01
10006       2021-04-03      Benny's true                1               2021-03-01
```

**DDL & DML**

```
CREATE TABLE worker_log
    (log_date timestamp, total_workers int, store varchar(8));

CREATE TABLE request_log
    (ticket_no int, request_date timestamp, store varchar(8));
    

INSERT INTO worker_log
    (log_date, total_workers,store)
VALUES
    ('2021-01-01 00:00:00', 2, 'Ralphs'),
    ('2021-02-01 00:00:00', 0, 'Ralphs'),
    ('2021-03-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Ralphs'),
    ('2021-01-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Benny''s'),
    ('2021-02-01 00:00:00', 0, 'Benny''s'),
    ('2021-03-01 00:00:00', 1, 'Benny''s')
;
INSERT INTO request_log
    (ticket_no, request_date, store)
VALUES
    (10000, '2021-01-03 00:00:00', 'Ralphs'),
    (10001, '2021-01-08 00:00:00', 'Ralphs'),
    (10002, '2021-02-05 00:00:00', 'Ralphs'),
    (10003, '2021-04-03 00:00:00', 'Ralphs'),
    (10004, '2021-01-21 00:00:00', 'Benny''s'),
    (10005, '2021-02-23 00:00:00', 'Benny''s'),
    (10006, '2021-04-03 00:00:00', 'Benny''s')
;
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/63a4b1/1

Comment: I revised my answer to use a `left join lateral` that matches your expected result (I believe)

Answer (score 0):

Usage of:

- **Left join** - as described in below link.[1]

Request_log table(left one):

Checks all records for requested_date.
If date is covered by example of second table and log_date matches.
Then are applied at the beginning two cases from case expression.
Last one is to cover records which might exists in request_log table but not in worker_log table and covers possible null records.

[1] [Why use left join at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436507/why-use-left-join-at-all#39437088)

- **Case expression** includes exact criteria of your need,presented by 3 options:

1. Applies to false condition
2. Applies to true condition
3. Not applies to our previous conditions

```sql
select  
r.ticket_no,
r.request_date, 
r.store, 
case  
when
   w.total_workers = 0 
     then 'false' 
when 
   w.total_workers > 0 
     then 'true'
else 'N/A' 
  end as workers_available 
from 
  request_log r 
left join 
  worker_log w on  r.request_date=w.log_date
```

Comment: Code-only answers are poor. Please explain why/how this answers the question. [answer] [Help] Please indent code reasonably. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts.

Comment: `case` is an *expression* (not a statement)

Comment: Repeating code in prose or repeating semantics of operators is not helpful. It is redundant & it does not explain why that is the code that was written to solve the problem. Also your prose is fragmented, unclear & vague. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.